# Woo commerce orders mails are not coming in inbox, error message- could not instantiate mail function

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using Woo commerce storefront theme and my orders emails are not coming into my inbox and then installed WP mail log and error message is could not instantiate mail function please provide me solution

Comment: You should check if the mail() function is enabled or not in your PHP-environment.

Comment: i am also using contact form 7 and emails from contact form 7 are coming into my inbox but orders emails are not

Comment: Rohit, did you do all the setting like this link ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46031261/woo-commerce-orders-mails-are-not-coming-in-inbox-error-message-could-not-inst

Comment: @Aki you are talking about which link ??

Comment: https://www.fixrunner.com/fix-email-notifications-woocommerce/

Comment: if you already did all the configuration settings than , can you disable your contact form 7 for while to check the email conflict issue?

Comment: deactivated my contact form 7 now what you want me to do ?

Comment: error is      could not instantiate mail function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used pepipost plugin to bypass phpmailer function now mail is sent usinng SMTP.
first of all, need to create an account on pepipost and verify your domain then an API key will generate paste that API key in your pepipost wordpress plugin

Answer (score 0):

One more tip I will add here. Make sure to use the server's IP address where your website is pointing as SMTP hostname .

Because email from website (that is contact form) are used to run from the server where your website is pointing.